# Get height of Bootstrap element as it would be on a smaller screen

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and a template (http://aqvatarius.com/themes/index.php?template=intuitive)

I have a report with a table. The fields are name, phone, email and notes. The notes field is about 2 lines on a desktop but about 4 lines when printing.

The theme resizes content div heights on load and on window resize. This means that when I print something from a desktop, the print view is clipped because the content div heights have been set before the notes text has been wrapped and increased the height of the table.

I can get around this by resizing my window first, then printing. Obviously this is not ideal for my users.

The question(s): If I am currently looking at a desktop (`lg`) and the print paper width is more like small (`sm`) can I get the height of the table as if it were `sm`? Or can my print button resize the viewport, print then resize back? Or are there any other methods I can pursue?

Comment: Still curious re the original question, but I have a workaround for myself: I'll have the print button, simply resize the table, then trigger a window resize, then print, then resize the table back.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can test:

```
if($(window).width() >= 1024){
var top_nav_height = $("#id_of_top_nav").height();
var bottom_nav_height = $("#id_of_bottom_nav").height();  
}
```